# App exits while launching activity from notification when application is killed

Tags: android, notifications

I need to create notification and it is working fine with the code given below. And when I click the notification it will redirect to a activity, say activity2. I can enter this activity2 from other activities or fragments, say activity1, fragment1 etc. While I'm staying on application and click the notification, it will redirect to activity2 and while I press back button it will go to the previous activity or fragment. But if I kill the application and clicked the notification, it will open up activity2, but on pressing back button, the app will exit. I need it to be redirected to activity1. How can I do it.
Thanks in advance.

```
    void createDownloadNotification(String title) {
    if (title != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STRING, title);
        intent.putExtra("id", i);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);




        Notification myNotification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText("Some text....")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(false).build();


        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(i + 1, myNotification);
        i = i + 1;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your current implementation and the `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);` part, the behavior in question happens by design. Understanding [tasks and backstacks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html) would explain that.

You would want to launch an activity with conditions in `onBackPressed` of `activity2`, detecting whenever it has arrived from a notification while recreating it if the activity doesn't exist.

Going through [activity launch modes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) would help. You could use that with `activity1` for your implementation.

[Understand android activity launchmode](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en) is a good blog article, the only non-android developers link in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to setup parent activity in manifest file and create stacks for your resultant activity.'

Here is the very nice [tutorial](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse) to get your started.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as per the definition here: [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

The intent you put in your `PendingIntent` for the notification, closes all the open `Activities` and opens `SecondActivity`. If you remove that flag from your `Intent`, it won't close the others.

In addition to that, you may add parent `Activity` to your `SecondActivity` so that it knows where to go when the user presses back and there was nothing open before the notification was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Method**

pass a bool via the intent you use to get to the activity2

from notification then pass bool true

from open activity then pass bool false

and get bool value in activity 2 and set accordingly

after that set onBackPressed in Activity 2 as this

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (fromNotification) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this,
                    Activity1.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```